# Windows 98 drive image

Tags: backup, windows-backup, windows-98, norton-ghost

I have one PC with windows 98. It doesn't have USB or CD-Rom, but it has floppy drive and Network.

I need to make drive image. Can I do it with Norton ghost ?
I mean Norton ghost on floppy drive as bootable and then save backup on network location.

Comment: does it have PXE BOOT on that network card?

Comment: If your version of ghost has network support, then you can do it, add more details of your ghost version.

Comment: I need to check PXE BOOT.
For the time being I don't have any Norton Ghost. I need to ask some of my friends I remember some of them using it during win98/win xp age. Some might still have it.

Answer (score 0):

Norton Ghost is no longer developed or supported. One good solution that uses GPL software is CloneZilla[CloneZilla website](https://clonezilla.org/). It's free, open source, actively maintained and has the following features that you're asking for:

1. CloneZilla will boot off the network using PXE
2. It will let you save your image to an SMB share, ssh, nfs or webdav over the network

The only annoying part will be setting up the PXE server to boot CloneZilla, but you'll need this for any drive image-level creation. Another option might be to take the hard drive out of the Windows 98 machine and plug it into a new host using a USB-to-IDE adapter and then boot CloneZilla on that using a USB stick

Answer (score -2):

I'm not certain that an older version of Norton will do it, but you should try backing to a drive image to Dropbox or other virtual space.  You will need a good Internet connection and it is advisable to encrypt the image backup.